# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException in WCF and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wcf

this is my code in ViewModel:

```
 private AccountServiceClient asc = new AccountServiceClient();


        public MainViewModel()
        {
            var i = asc.GetAccountByName("what");
        }
```

this is my code in WCF ( AccountService ):

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
    {
        private DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
        public Account GetAccountByName(string namelogin)
        {
            return db.Accounts.Where(t => t.NameLogin.Equals(namelogin)).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

I has to refesh both of them but It aslo show this :

[image]

> "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'An error occurred while
>   receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://localhost:52017/AccountService.svc. This could be due to the
>   service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also
>   be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
>   (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more
>   details.' "

I'm sure that I have data account in my database;

Comment: Is your WCF service running?

Comment: yes, It running

Comment: Are you able to reach it through a browser?

Comment: yes, i do it through a browser

Comment: Hmm... it should be something trivial. Can you debug the WCF service and see if it hits a breakpoint anywhere?

Comment: What happens if you open `http://localhost:52017/AccountService.svc` in your browser? Does it show the service info page? Or does it throw an error. If it is the latter you need to fix that first

Comment: It seems that your service not working properly. How do you ensure that the service working properly? Please try to update the service reference before we consume it.

Comment: HAve you tried to look into any binding mismatches maybe?